# Ajax в Spring MVC добавление записи в таблицу

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, controller

Всем добрый день!
Вопрос такой, есть jsp страница на которой таблица со списком учеников и форма добавления нового ученика, я хочу при заполнении этой формы и отправке данных с нее подгружать эти данные в таблицу со студентами по средствам ajax, то есть обновлять только таблицу.

У меня контроллер, который отображает эту страницу

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/students"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView students(){
    ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView();
    List<Student> list = studentService.getAll();
    mov.addObject("studentList", list);
    mov.setViewName("students");
    return mov;
}
```

Собственно jsp страница, где таблица со студентами

```
<div class="tableStudents">
<table border="2" bgcolor="#C1CDCD" >
    <th colspan="3">Студенты</th>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><B>Имя</B></td>
        <td align="center"><B>Фамилия</B></td>
        <td align="center"><B>Дата поступления</B></td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">${student.firstName}</td>
                <td align="center">${student.lastName}</td>
                <td align="center">${student.entranceYear}</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href="<c:url value='/profile/student/${student.id}' />">Профиль</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Форма добавления ученика

```
<div class="studentAdd">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${edit eq true}">
        <h2>Форма редактирования студента</h2>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <h2>Форма добавления студента</h2>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="firstName">Имя: </label> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="lastName">Фамилия: </label> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="entranceYear">Дата поступления(dd/mm/yyyy): </label> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="entranceYear" id="entranceYear"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${edit eq true}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Обновить"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" id="add" onClick="add()"/>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

На этой же странице я вначале подключаю jquery и сам скрипт в конце

```
<script>
$("add").click(function (){
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    var entranceYear = $("#entranceYear").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "studentAdd",
        data: {"firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "entranceYear": entranceYear },
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
            <table border="2" bgcolor="#C1CDCD" >
                    <th colspan="3">Студенты</th>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><B>Имя</B></td>
                        <td align="center"><B>Фамилия</B></td>
                        <td align="center"><B>Дата поступления</B></td>
                    </tr>
            $.each(data, function(index, student){
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">student.firstName</td>
                        <td align="center">student.lastName</td>
                        <td align="center">student.entranceYear</td>
                        <td align="center">
                        <a href="<c:url value='/profile/student/student.id' />">Профиль</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        }
    })
}
```

Вот контроллер, который должен принять данные, добавить в базу нового студента и вернуть обновленный список

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/studentAdd"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Student> add(@RequestParam("firstName")String firstName,
                                       @RequestParam("lastName")String lastName,
                                       @RequestParam("entranceYear")LocalDate entranceYear){
    studentService.save(new Student(firstName, lastName, entranceYear));
    List<Student>studentList=studentService.getAll();
    return studentList;
}
```

Но данные у меня передаются не POST, а GET и в url не указывается имя обработчика, поэтому данные контроллеру не приходят, вот url

```
http://localhost:8080/university/?firstName=Тест&lastName=Студент&entranceYear=22%2F02%2F2016
```

В чем может быть проблема и как это все правильно организовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят, проблема была в отсутствующей библиотеке jackson-mapper-asl